# Design plan for new iOS application using Realm

Tags: objective-c, realm, realm-object-server

I am very new to Realm and its technology, but have an idea for a sports application that the realm object server and its synchronisation could really help, but am unsure how I should set it up.

So I want to be able to share between a group of players from the mobile app, e.g. members of a darts club.  The data will be the players details and past scores against each player that has had a match.

Of course if the group is a venue, a given player could be a member of more than 1 group.

Is this possible using Realm?  I want to give the flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it should be possible. :)

Realm Mobile Platform allows the creation of private Realms for each user, but these can then be shared with other user accounts (Using [the new permissions feature](https://realm.io/news/realtime-collaboration-now-for-every-mobile-developer/)).

Alternatively, RMP also allows the creations of public Realms that all users can read from by default, but I believe can be overridden if required.

In any case, while it depends on your app's exact needs and how you plan to architect it, yes, having shared data amongst multiple groups should be possible. :)